# The content of a screen is not centered after pushReplacement

Tags: flutter

the code

```
checkConnection().then((value) {
  if (value == true) {
    debugPrint('AllMessagesView, Bad Server');
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FailWithMessage(message: kBadServer)),
    );
  }

  debugPrint('2');
  return FailWithMessage(message: kBadConnection);
});

debugPrint('1');
return const Scaffold(body: CircularProgressIndicator());
```

gives the following output

```
---checkConnection---
I/flutter ( 6874): 1
I/flutter ( 6874): AllMessagesView, Bad Server
I/flutter ( 6874): 2
```

and the content of the FailWithMessage() is not in the center of screen

the body of the FailWithMessage:

```
body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [ ...
```

Why the result is not centered?

Comment: Wrap Column with `Center` widget. does it solve?

Comment: You can wrap FailWithMessage() with center

Answer (score 0):

use below code in your `Column`

> ```
>                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
> ```